# Lightning calender add-on will not change to month view

Tags: thunderbird

On my Raspberry Pi which is running Raspbian I installed Icedove and got the Thunderbird calender add-on (Lightning). When I opened it for the first time it came up in week view, and since I like to view my calender in month view I tried to change it to month view by pressing the button that when I hovered over it said "Switch to month view.". Nothing happened so I reinstalled Lightning and tried again. I got the same outcome as the first time and I am wondering if anyone has had the same problem and has figured out how to fix it.

Have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you recognized also editing calenders (and tasks) is nearly impossible... that happens since icedove 24.x because of different internally lifetime linking inside lightning!

---

the easiest way to solve this is described in the [debian-wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Icedove#Icedove_and_the_Mozilla_Lightning_Extension):
**uninstall** the ***lightning*** add-on and **install** ***iceowl-extension*** via your package manager (or terminal: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y iceowl-extension`).

Comment: Or replace the ice* packages with the real Mozilla tarballs.